# TinyMCE in JSP (Struts application)

Tags: html, jsp, struts, tinymce

Which download I need to use to use TinyMCE in JSP(Struts application)

I see Main Package, Development Package and also different Compression packages.

I am trying to implement Rich text editor for a text area in our application.

Answer (score 1):

The compression packages are just compressed versions of the main package - you should be careful about using them because they can cause a lot of load on the client-side. The development package will probably be an unstable version of the code, so you should probably use the main package to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.
Answering my own quesion: We need to copy the entire folder to the project and edit the Jsp as per examples in the website.

I used main package.